# SSAS "The Subscription identifier is invalid"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, sql-agent, sql-data-warehouse

We switched from a SQL server 2017 to a newer SQL server 2019. We deployed all our SSIS-packages in the same way to the newer server. Since then we have often the same error on processing-tasks like cube-processing or dimension-processing on the newer server:

> Error: Trace: The Subscription identifier is invalid; it must be unique when subscribing and the identifier of a registerd subscription when unsubscribing.

So our jobs are failing. Some jobs are scheduled every ten minutes. They don't fail always, but sometimes within a day.

I changed our SSIS-package with SSAS-tasks from a projecttype of sql server 2017 to the projecttype of sql server 2019, but this didn't solve this problem. I have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: Same. This is happening to me on both a newly-installed SQL Server 2019 deployment and on a deployment from several years ago that was recently updated. I don't think it used to happen on the old deployment but it was a prototype system that wasn't in use so I don't have records to confirm.

Comment: As a workaround we're repeating the processing-tasks within OnError-event of SSIS. In most cases this helps but very seldom our tasks even fail a second time in this event.